# Is there any way of saving this blurry photo???

Tags: photo-editing, focus, image-quality, blur, image-manipulation

[http://i.imgur.com/Lb9FXGe.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/Lb9FXGe.jpg)

Is there ANY way to save this blurry photo? I have photoshop. PLEASE HELP.

Comment: This is a much higher resolution picture than the one in the other question, so this is a good candidate for applying deconvolution methods to. If tbair has the original raw picture then that would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

The picture is badly out of focus, and most of the details are gone. You can do things like running an unsharp mask, high pass filter, or other sharpening filters but you are not going to get television csi level recovery. You can also adjust the contrast of the picture and downsize the picture to increase the perceived sharpness. In this picture I used unsharp mask, high pass, and camera raw sharpening which introduced artifacts and other defects. I also changed the curve to high and adjusted individual colors to maximize contrast. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuNrV.jpg

Comment: Thank you!!! That looks so much better than all my attempts!