# How to remove the blur in the raw image(.cr2) using photoshop cc 2018

Tags: raw, photo-editing, blur

I'm new to photography. The raw picture(.cr2) is out of focus. It focuses background instead of the person in the picture, and the person in the picture is really blurred, and the background is very clear. How to unblur the area of the person in the picture.

Camera: Canon 6D
Lens: 50mm 1.8f

Comment: Related: [How can slightly blurred photos be improved in post processing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4724/15871) and [How can I fix the blur in this photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/89070/15871) and [How can I fix an out of focus photo? Is there an app for that? I don't have Photoshop](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/92194/15871) and [Is there any way of saving this blurry photo???](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/71238/15871) and [How can I repair missed focus in a valuable photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/24042/15871)

Answer (score 6):

You must be under the impression that focus is a captured attribute akin to exposure; something that can be tweaked after the shot was made.

This is incorrect.

If your shot is OOF, it’s OOF. Only thing you can do is reshoot.